# Why does Kubernetes Ingress return 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

Im new to Kubernetes and want to set up an Ingress for my cluster but i get a 502 Bad Gateway error.
The pods, service and ingress are created successfully and don't show any errors. When i had configured a different ingress service for a different project it worked fine. This is the error i get in the nginx controller:

> 2023-09-11 19:09:56 2023/09/11 17:09:56 [error] 2385#2385: *218434 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.65.4, server: _, request: "GET /ticket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.0.252:8000/", host: "localhost"
>
> 2023-09-11 19:09:56 192.168.65.4 - - [11/Sep/2023:17:09:56 +0000] "GET /ticket HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 2601 0.000 [default-ticket-application-service-8000] [] 10.1.0.253:8000, 10.1.0.254:8000, 10.1.0.252:8000 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.001, 0.000 502, 502, 502 8cc88b8a483dd76b820b7da78260b6fd

ingress-service.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-project
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /ticket
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ticket-application-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

ticket-application-service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ticket-application-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: ticketApp
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

ticket-application-deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ticket-application-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: ticketApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: ticketApp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ticket-app
          image: borjanob/ticket_app:55da0f121ba6432da3c5afdf48950a00bc431e29
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 8000
```

Dockerfile for building the image in the deployment:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY TicketApplication/TicketApplication.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "./TicketApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TicketApplication/TicketApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TicketApplication/TicketApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TicketApplication.dll"]
```

I tried changing the port numbers to 80 but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> When i had configured a different ingress service for a different project it worked fine.

It seems to me that the error was probably some issue on the project that you are building. Have you tried running the image (not using kubernetes) but just docker run image:tag and try to perform a simple curl to the docker container? (e.g. curl localhost:80)

If it failed, the error might be related to the image you are building.

To further prove the point, you can run a simple pod,service and ingress (e.g. nginx) and see if it returns the same 502 error.

Comment: I tried to perform a curl to the docker container and i returns the html like it should. I also tried running another pod, service and ingress and it works.

Comment: Hello @borjanob, can you try to upload a sample docker image in docker hub. So I can help test your setup. Or any image that somehow in a similar setup.

Comment: Sure I can. The image I am using in the cluster is on the ticket_app repository link: https://hub.docker.com/r/borjanob/ticket_app . I am using the latest version. The Dockerfile used to build the image is in the question description. The image I am using for the database is https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore . My dockerhub account is https://hub.docker.com/u/borjanob

Comment: Hello borjanob, I manage to run the docker application. Kindly see attached image: https://imgur.com/a/MSgi8bJ

1. Ensure that you have the ingressClassName field in your ingress resource.
2. install nginx ingress controller via this link: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

Thanks! Happy to connect with Linkedin!